# Web Api & Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a problem while calling a service using $http.
I am opening an .aspx page using iframe and on the page load i want to call a service which i written in the controller but $http is taking full path of the page and then path of the web api service as shown below.

http://localhost:50802/TST00111CFG/app/DispatchNotify/api/DispatchNotifyService/GetWorkOrders

and i want in the below manner

http://localhost:50802/TST00111CFG/api/DispatchNotifyService/GetWorkOrders

My controller code is like this

```
dbSrvc.getDatFromService('api/DispatchNotifyService/GetWorkOrders', $scope.workOrder).then(function (result) {
    debugger;
});
```

Please help me out in this.

dnApp.service('dbSrvc', ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {

```
var getDataService = function (url, val) {
    debugger;
    var deferObj = $q.defer();
    $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'Get',
        data: val
    }).then(function (data) {

        deferObj.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferObj.promise;
};

var postDataService = function (url, val) {
    debugger;
    var deferObj = $q.defer();
    $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'Post',
        data: val
    }).then(function (data) {


        deferObj.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferObj.promise;
};

return {
    getDatFromService: getDataService, //To Get Data From Service
    postDataToService: postDataService //To Send Data and Retrieve from Service
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code for dbSrvc.getDatFromService?

Comment: localhost is only available in your computer

Comment: yes localhost is my machine

Comment: jbrown now is it fine?

Comment: @Lav -  no, I don't see the service code.

Comment: @jbrown- please check now i have updated service code also

Comment: @Lav - ok, so I would suggest being more specific in your url definition.  Typically in a service you'd prepend a prefix like http://localhost:50802/TST00111CFG (http:// is getting stripped from this) to the url string that was passed in.  That way you can easily change the prefix when you move from dev to production to allow for the possibility of your api being on a different domain.

Comment: As @jbrown suggested: Use an absolute path instead of a relative path.